# How to assign and dynamically change the name of a dataframe in R in a loop

Tags: r

Hi am trying to create dataframes in a loop with different names, what is assigned to them is a filter from another dataframe inside the loop

here is the code I have so far

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data_s_y_revenue)){
  
  name_y <- data_s_y_revenue$year[i]
  
  data_y_y <-filter(data_y, year==name_y)
  
  
}
```

the `name_y` is a variable that as it loops it gets a year value, 2018, 2019,2020, etc, as the code is right now the dataframe `data_y_y` gets rewritten every time, what I would like to end with is a way that the name of the variable has the VALUE of `name_y` variable on its name, and I end with as many dataframes as years there is, for example if I have only year 2019 and 2020, I would end with 2 dataframes with names `2020_data_y_y` and `2019_data_y_y` with the values of the filter for those years.

Thanks for the help.

some data example
data_s_y_revenue data:

```
year 
2018
2019
```

data_y data:

```
year   value value2
2018   1     4
2018   2     4
2019   3     2
2019   3     2
```

the expected result would be 2 dataframes called `2019_data_y_y` and `2020_data_y_y` with the filtered values

Comment: Please provide some example data and the expected output (show us the structure/data you expect as output). I'm sure there's a better way than using a loop

Comment: you could have a look at [assign](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/assign)

Comment: @Waldi I was able to make it work with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the suggestion of Waldi I was able to solve it

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data_s_y_revenue)){
  
  name_y <- data_s_y_revenue$year[i]
  
  name_y1 <- paste("data_y_y",name_y, sep="_")
  data_y_y <-filter(data_y, year==name_y)
  
  assign(name_y1, data_y_y)
  
}
```